# Editing element data for each element in a selectAll in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

In the block -

http://bl.ocks.org/whatsthebeef/6456877

I am trying to add an attribute to data for each item in the `selectAll()`. I interpreted this [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data) as saying this should work but it doesn't. I also tried it with some CSV files which drew circle onto the map in the same manner and that didn't work either. I understand there are other options such as using datum after `enter()` which does work but I have other use cases where this would be too late.

When the commented out code `// .data(countries)` is uncommented and the current `data(function(d){....})` is removed it does work correctly.

Does anyone know if what I am doing is possible and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/sRSAy/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I notice you are returning the index and not the data. This is what I missed. You should create an answer with this information and I will up mark it as it may be useful to others. I do however understand that this isn't good practice as the purpose of this callback is more to define which data to bind to and not to manipulate the data.

Comment: Not quite sure that you mean by "return index" -- are you talking about the key that gets used to match data? Is this what you are having trouble with (i.e. data isn't matched as it should be)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Sorry, what I wrote didn't make much sense. In my block in the callback function of 'data()' I am returning the first parameter 'd' where as you a returning the actual value of foo for d. Having said that the value which you are returning seems fairly arbitrary.

Comment: This value will determine how data gets matched, so it does matter in real applications. In my example, it doesn't as I only do the `selectAll` once.

Comment: Have you tried returning something else? Maybe it's the complex data structure that's messing things up.

Comment: Yes, it's the complex data structure which is creating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want in that manner, i.e. something like

```
.data(data, function(d) { d.bar = 10; return d.foo; })
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sRSAy/).

Whether it is a good idea to do that is a different question, to which the answer is almost certainly no.

Answer (score 1):

The optional second argument of data is for a [key function](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/). I would suggest adding the property to countries w/ a `forEach`:

```
var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;
countries.forEach(function(d){ d.code = "1"; });

svg.selectAll("path:not(.graticule)")
    .data(countries)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path);
```

http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/6459380